# (JAXB) Recuperar lo fichero XML en los campos de entrada del formulario JSwing con unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, java-swing, jpa, jaxb

Soy nuevo y empezé esos días a aprender XML por cuenta de una implementación que debe tener en mi aplicación, ya hice algunos testes con `marshall()` y `unmarshall()` ya en `Main()` para entiender más, estoy haciendo un formulario que tienes la siguiente operación: el usuario presiona na opción Procurar `XML`, entonces seleciona un fichero en ese formato en algun fichero del sistema para después importar el para la aplicación y o que estoy intentando hacer es que cuando el importar el en sistema ese puede leer y en cada tag de cierto tipo el carga cada una en su respectiva `JTextField, JCombobox y JSpinner`.
Ejemplo:

```html
<Pedido>
   <pedidos>
   <pedido id = "1">
      <dataCadastro>3917-04-11T00:00:00-03:00</dataCadastro>  <!-- tfDataCadastro: getText(); -->
      <nomeProduto>Produto C</nomeProduto>     <!-- cbProduto.getSelectedItem(); -->
      <numControle>41666</numControle>    <!-- tfNumControle: getText(); -->
      <quantidade>4</quantidade>    <!-- tfQuantidade: getText(); -->
      <valorUnitario>41.46</valorUnitario>    <!-- tfValorUnitario: getText(); -->
      <codCliente>6</codCliente>     <!-- cbCodCliente.getSelectedItem(); -->
   </pedido>
</Pedido>

<!-- Las tags comentadas son valores a sean recuperados en los campos -->
```

Intenté hacer asi pero no se se es un buen camiño para empezar:

DAOManager:

```js
public interface DAOManager {
    
    ClienteDAO getClienteDAO();
    
    PedidoDAO getPedidoDAO();
    
    ProdutoDAO getProdutoDAO();
}
```

Pedido (la clase que estoy deseando cargar el xml):

```js
@XmlRootElement(name = "pedido")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido")
public class Pedido implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataCadastro;
    @Column
    private String nomeProduto;
    @Column
    private int numControle;
    @Column
    private int quantidade;
    @Column(precision=15, scale=7)
    private float valorUnitario;
    @Column
    private Integer codCliente;
    @Column(precision=15, scale=7)
    private float valorTotal;
    @Column(precision=2, scale=2)
    private Double total;

    
    public Pedido() {
    }
    
    
    public Pedido(int numControle, Date dataCadastro, String nomeProduto, float valorUnitario, float valorTotal, int quantidade, int codCliente, Double total){
        this.numControle = numControle;
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
        this.nomeProduto = nomeProduto;
        this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
        this.codCliente = codCliente;
        this.total = total;
    }

    /* Getters e setters del la aplicación */
         
    
}
```

MySQLPedidoDAO:

```js
/**
 *
 * @author Vickz
 */
public class MySQLPedidoDAO implements PedidoDAO {

    //null pointer exception pois esse campo estava inicializado como null antes
    public ConnectionFactory cf;

    
    public MySQLPedidoDAO(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.cf = cf;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void inserir(Pedido o) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        //tanto persist quanto merge salvam o objeto no banco de dados 
        //em.persist(cliente);
        cf.createEm().merge(o);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void alterar(Pedido o) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
        pedido.getId();
        cf.createEm().merge(o);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(Pedido o) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        cf.createEm().remove(o);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Pedido pesquisar(Long id) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        //erro abaixo
        Pedido pedido = cf.createEm().find(Pedido.class, id);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        //erro ao deletar pois o factory já está fechado
        //emf.close();
        return pedido;
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<Pedido> listar() {
        cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        //pedido = *, Pedido = nome da tabela
        Query consulta = cf.createEm().createQuery("select pedido from Pedido pedido");
        List<Pedido> pedidos = consulta.getResultList();
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
        return pedidos;
    }

    
}
```

ViewPedidos:

```js
public class ViewPedidos extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    private DAOManager manager;
    private PedidoModel model;
    private MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao;
    private MySQLClienteDAO mscdao;
    private MySQLProdutoDAO msprdao;
    private List<Produto> produtos;
    private List<Pedido> pedidos;
    private Pedido ped;
    private Produto pro;
    private FiltroArquivo filter;
    private String xmlFile = "";
    private boolean editavel;
    private JAXBContext context;
 
    /* ....  Getters y Setters .... */

    private void btImportarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        try {
            habilitarTextFieldEBotoes();
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ImportarPedidoList.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Pedido pedido = (Pedido) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(xmlFile));
            // Y a partir de ahora estoy intentando procurar como debe ser //hecho eso
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Não foi possível importar o arquivo.xml", "Falha ao carregar", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                          


    private void btProcurarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        try {
            JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\Users\\Vickz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Loja");
            jFileChooser.setDialogTitle("Escolha o arquivo xml");
            jFileChooser.setFileFilter(new FiltroArquivo(".xml", "Arquivo XML"));
            int result = jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
            if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, jFileChooser.getName());
                xmlFile = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Não foi possível carregar o arquivo.xml", "Falha ao carregar", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                          

                 
/*
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {

        if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          String value = ie.getItem().toString();
          // faz algo conforme a opção selecionada
          if (value.equals("Produto A")) {

          } else if (value.equals("Produto B")) {
          
          } else if (value.equals("Produto C")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto D")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto E")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto F")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto G")) {
              
          } else if (value.equals("Produto H")) {
               
          } else if (value.equals("Produto I")) {
                            
          }
       }
    }*/

}
```

Intenté hacer un test en Main() pero no consigo también:

```js
public class Main {

    private static JAXBContext context;
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
    MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao = new MySQLPedidoDAO(cf);
    PedidoList pl = new PedidoList();
    

    Main.context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Pedido.class);
    //Marshaller marshaller = Main.context.createMarshaller();
    //marshaller.marshal(new Pedido(41666, new java.util.Date(2017, 3, 11), "Produto C", 41.46f, 0, 4, 6, 235.54), new File("pedido.xml"));
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = Main.context.createUnmarshaller();
    Pedido pedidolist = (Pedido) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("C:\\Users\\Vickz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Loja\\pedido.xml"));
    
    Marshaller marshaller = Main.context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(pedidolist, System.out);
    
    
    /*for(PedidoList pedidolis: unmarshalledPedido.getPedidos()){
         System.out.println(pedido.getDataCadastro());
         System.out.println(pedido.getNomeProduto());
         System.out.println(pedido.getNumControle());
         System.out.println(pedido.getQuantidade());
         System.out.println(pedido.getValorUnitario());
         System.out.println(pedido.getCodCliente());
         System.out.println(pedido.getValorTotal());
         System.out.println(pedido.getTotal());
    }*/
}
```

Alguién sabe algún camiño para recorrer todo formulário recién importado y recuperar lo valor de cada tag y poner cada una en un campo? Abajo siguen los botones hablados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A menos que con campo te refieras a un JTextField, podrías por ejemplo usar alguno de los modelos de Swing, ListModel, TreeModel, o mi recomendación particular TableModel para pasarle tus datos y que solito se encargue de renderizarlos por tí.